# Unable to resize polygons/lines imported from Google Earth PRO Using KML Tools

Tags: qgis, polygon, qgis-3, google-earth-pro

I imported all my files from Google Earth Pro into QGIS and I need to resize some of the polygons (after agricultural job is done, some of fields get bigger or smaller; from corn we go to soy etc.)  My problem is that I am not able to resize any of fields/polygons which are imported. If I create a new polygon than I am able to resize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error source #1: You didn't save the imported polygons as a shapefile.

Error source #2: You didn't switch on editing.

Comment: I did switch on editting but still that Vertex tool is greyed so i cannot click on it which leads me to #1 which i did not do, do I need to do it part by part? or can import somehow all polygons at same time?

Comment: Mark all files you want to import and then drag & drop them into QGis.

Comment: I think u didnt understand my question. I asked how to import Polygons as shapefile, I have them into QGIS already.

Comment: Right click and save. And maybe merge all polygons of the same type into a layer first.

Comment: Hmm on right click i have export and there are Save Feature As, Save as Layer Definition File,  Save as QGIS Layer File, I guess i choose 1st and what is next to do ? Under format I choose ESRI Shapefile?

Comment: And if i do so I get this error :/ Export to vector file failed.
Error: Creation of layer failed (OGR error: Failed to create file Kukuruz.shp: Permission denied) Sorry for bothering u, but this is important for me and your help is amazing!

Comment: Choose a different path to save under, obviously you don't have permission to save at the location you want to save to.

Comment: You also get that error if you only typed the layer name into the text box; you need to put an entire filepath (eg C:\Documents\myshapefile.shp).