# How to exclude one specific polygon from a layer which have like 20 diffirent polygons?

Tags: polygon, vector, qgis-3

I have a layer with like 20 polygons which I imported from Google Earth Pro.

And what I am trying to do is to exclude (isolate) that one big polygon which is in a way of all other smaller ones so they are not visible under big one.

I know that one way is to make it transparent, but while doing that all other polygons will become transparent aswell.

So what i need is like a tool or something which will help me to "extract" only one specific polygon from all those in a same layer, into another layer, and after that i can transform it into lines (Vectors) so there will only left boundarys of that specific polygon which can be seen on picture, or even make it transparent.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I transform a polygon to a linestring in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15819/how-can-i-transform-a-polygon-to-a-linestring-in-qgis) - answer is old but still valid

Comment: Yes Erik you are right but I am using QGIS3.2 and it is diffirent than 1.7 so can you describe me how to do it? And can you add new tag QGIS-3.4 Madeira :)

Comment: I would be rather surprised if the name of the tool changed substantially.

Comment: Yeah it is same but problem is that when i imported from GE there are a lot polygons on same layer so I have one which is really big and over whole map and I am not able to shut it down, so that is why i was thinking changing it to line, but not whole layer just that one specific one.

Comment: Do you simply want to be able to see what is underneath? Then change the style of that layer. Do you want to remove that polygon from the layer? Then mark it, use `save as` to export the marked polygon to a new file and then delete it from the old layer.

Comment: @erik Yeah i saved it but now hard part is how to delte it coz delete button is grayed out I cannot click on it

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/299843/unable-to-resize-polygons-lines-imported-from-google-earth-pro-using-kml-tools

Comment: *What* lines? Do you want the boundary? Do you want all possible line segments between any two points on the boundary? What result do you want?

Comment: @jpmc26 Yeah i want to have just boundarys of that specific polygon you cann se on picture :) https://i.stack.imgur.com/q98pE.png

Comment: Still on hold? I changed it completly pls mods

Answer (score 3):

If you write line in the search box of Processing toolbox in QGIS 3.4, you will have Polygons to lines:

[image]